# Replace matched pattern with array list

Tags: vim, replace

I have a HTML code like this.

```
<tr>
  <td>$value</td>
  <td>$value</td>
  <td>$value</td>
</tr>
```

I want to changes all `$value` with a value from an array `new_value = ['Noodle', 'Rice', 'Pizza']` I thought it will be solved if doing some macro things, here is my first attempt.

```
:let new_value = ['Noodle', 'Rice', 'Pizza']
:let i = 0
qq
/$value
:s/$value/\=new_value[i]/
:let i += 1
q
```

But when I run this macro, it's not running smoothly.

Comment: Isn't that typically the job of a scripting language like PHP?

Comment: Indeed, I'm just using it as example of my problem. Not actually using it with PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move down one line in the macro. As it currently stands you run the substitute command on the same line every time. So only the first `$value` is replaced. (assuming your cursor started on the first `<td>` line.)

```
:let new_value = ['Noodle', 'Rice', 'Pizza']
:let i = 0
qq
/$value
:s/$value/\=new_value[i]/
:let i += 1
jq  <-- Added j
```

If you ran the macro as you currently have it would do the replacements properly if all the text was on one line.

---

Although a better solution would be this

```
:let new_value = ['Noodle', 'Rice', 'Pizza']
:%s/$value/\=remove(new_value, 0)/g
```

The first line creates a list of words and the second replaces all instances of `$value` with the head of the list. After this is done `new_value` will be empty. (assuming that the size of new_value is equal to the number of `$value`)

Comment: Your second solution it works perfectly, just curious, is 0 in second `remove` parameter that actually iterated until last element in `new_value`?

Comment: @Adam take a look at [`:h remove(`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#remove%28%29). The second parameter is the index of the item you wanted removed. `remove()` then returns that item and removes it from the list.

Comment: Ahh, I see. One last question, I try to add more character so it will become like this `:%s/$value/\[\=remove(new_value, 0)\]/g` but It's not print the value.

Comment: @Adam Since `\=` makes it so everything to the right of it is an expression you need to use string concatenation to get what you want. Ex: `:%s/$value/\='[' . remove(new_value,0) . ']'/g` surrounds the value returned with square brackets. Look at `:h sub-replace-\=`

Comment: Oh so Vim also can do concatenation too, big thanks for you Sir.